# Handling large gzfile in c++

Tags: c++, file, gzip

```
char buffer[1001];
for(;!gzeof(m_fHandle);){ 
         gzread(m_fHandle, buffer, 1000);
     The file I'm handling is more than 1GB.
```

do I load the entire file to the buffer? or should I malloc and allocate the size?

Or should I load it line by line? the file has a "\n" demarkating the EOL. if so, how do I do that for handling gzfile in c++?

Comment: Its not a good practice to load entire file of 1GB into program memory. Because, typically this memory resides in your RAM. Open, read and close the file wherever it is needed.

Comment: I need to read the complete file.. atleast line by line.
How do I do that?

Comment: @Bala your comment seems to miss the entire point of this question. Also, closing and reopening it is unrelated to memory usage. And freeing the memory and reallocating it repeatedly is going to make the situation _worse_ due to heap fragmentation

Comment: @sehe All i was trying to say is, it depends on size of RAM and if RAM is 1GB (>1GB no issues) its not good to load entire file. Rather when you open and read file line by line we are not allocating 1GB of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `zlib` approach would be:

You can just call `gzread` with a limited buffer size repeatedly. If you can be sure that he max line length is eg `BUFLEN`: See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a890ed2360cd411)**

```
#include <zlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

static const unsigned BUFLEN = 1024;

void error(const char* const msg)
{
    std::cerr << msg << "\n";
    exit(255);
}

void process(gzFile in)
{
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char* offset = buf;

    for (;;) {
        int err, len = sizeof(buf)-(offset-buf);
        if (len == 0) error("Buffer to small for input line lengths");

        len = gzread(in, offset, len);

        if (len == 0) break;    
        if (len <  0) error(gzerror(in, &err));

        char* cur = buf;
        char* end = offset+len;

        for (char* eol; (cur<end) && (eol = std::find(cur, end, '\n')) < end; cur = eol + 1)
        {
            std::cout << std::string(cur, eol) << "\n";
        }

        // any trailing data in [eol, end) now is a partial line
        offset = std::copy(cur, end, buf);
    }

    // BIG CATCH: don't forget about trailing data without eol :)
    std::cout << std::string(buf, offset);

    if (gzclose(in) != Z_OK) error("failed gzclose");
}

int main()
{
    process(gzopen("test.gz", "rb"));
}
```

If you cannot know the maximum line size, I'd suggest abstracting it a bit more and deriving from `std::basic_streambuf` overriding `underflow` so you can use `std::getline` with an `istream` based on this buffer.

**UPDATE** Since you're new to C++, implementing your own `streambuf` is likely ***not*** a good idea. I recommend using a c++ library (instead of zlib).

E.g. [Boost Iostream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/filter_usage.html) allows you to simply do this:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/772101d536a01fe4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>    

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main()
{   
    io::filtering_istream in;
    in.push(io::gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(io::file_source("my_file.txt"));
    // read from in using std::istream interface

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line, '\n'))
    {
         process(line); // your code :)
    }
}
```

---

Comment: What do you mean by '/ use std::rotate (or memmov?) to move the remaining input to the front and 
        // set offset to directly after the last available byte'?

Comment: I'm not implementing that, just giving you the idea. Since you're new to C++ and you probably /just want to read gzipped files/ - have you looked at using e.g. Boost IOStreams? Adding the documentation sample to my answer

Comment: boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp: No such file or directory :( looks like i've to use zlib only.

Comment: @pistal it's free and you might consider installing it. Of course, you can do the work. It's basically filling in the 'pseudocode comments' I left.

Comment: I did what you said for zlib.. and it still does not read the entire file.

Comment: @pistal Sure it does: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db43b317daa14d46 Just need to add the code that does your line-wise processing.

Comment: What I don't get is.. how do I do "while (found eol in [buf...(offset+len)))" ? I will try that..

Comment: @pistal I've cleaned up [the implementation of the pseudo code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a890ed2360cd411) now. Also added error reporting in case the input line length exceeds BUFLEN. Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to add `io::` before `gzip_decompressor` and `file_source`.

Comment: @Searene thanks, fixed (and [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/772101d536a01fe4))

Answer (score 0):

You say this is a gzfile. That implies a binary format where '\n' is not valid for EOL (there is no concept of EOL with binary files.)

That said, in practice you have a couple choices for buffer size. Loading the entire file into memory will certainly be easier for you as a developer to work with the data. However, this is a costly solution in terms of memory consumed for the task.

If memory is a concern then you need to work on the data in pieces. There is probably an optimal amount of data to try to fetch at a time and a lot of that will depend on the hardware architecture of the machine you have all the way from the CPU through cache lines, memory bus, SATA bus, and even the drives that hold the file itself.

If this is just a onesy-twosy kind of problem you're solving and you're running this on a modern computer, 1GB is probably ok to keep in memory. Just new a uint8_t[] the size of the file and read the whole thing in then parse the data.

Otherwise, you need to integrate your parsing of the file with the reading of the file.

Comment: Can I have a huge buffer atleast?

Comment: There are only 2 limits on the size of a normal buffer you may allocate.

1) How much memory is available in your system? 

This is usually the total RAM you have free. Typically on a modern system 1GB is probably available if you have just started a computer from reset.

2) What is the architecture you're building for? If this is a win32 project for example then you have a hard limit of buffers < 2^32 (about 4GB but probably less.) Even if you have 256 GB of ram on a 64-bit machine, if your binary is built for 32 then you're limited to 4GB. Still not a problem for your example given here.

Comment: zlib allows us to read gzfiles, right? How do I make it read the complete file.. that is my question.

Comment: Use heap memory like you said (instead of an array like you have in your code) Get the byte size of the file using the m_fHandle and then new[] that many bytes. Pass that buffer to gzread. Done.

Comment: an example would be fantastic. new to the world of c++.

Comment: @Lother that only tells you the compressed size on disk. Also, please don't post code in the comments. If you feel it's important enough, add it to the answer (or refer to an existing answer)

Comment: @sehe I apologize, I'm new to stackoverflow etiquette.